# Computed Key from Symbol in Typescript Interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make this code work:

```js
const userId: unique symbol = Symbol.for(`urn:${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV_VALUE}:claims/user-id`);

interface JwtPayload extends BaseJwtPayload {
  email: string;
  [userId]: string;
}
```

However, `console.log(userId)` gives the value `Symbol(urn:dev:claims/user-id)`.

How can I achieve the following:

```js
interface JwtPayload extends BaseJwtPayload {
  email: string;
  [`urn:${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV_VALUE}:claims/user-id`]: string;
}
```

without getting the error:

```
TS1169: A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.
```

Comment: What else did you expect? This absolutely follows the definition in the docs (first paragraph) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/for

Comment: Sorry @Felix, I clarified the question further.

Comment: I don't understand what this question has to do with symbols.  What specifically is wrong with the original version of the code; why is it bad that `console.log(userId)` gives you a symbol?  If you don't want symbols, then you should consider changing the title and removing everything before "How can I achieve the following". At which point, does this question differ from the [other one you posted later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66841911/dynamic-string-literal-type-from-variable-in-typescript)?  If not, can you close one of them?

Comment: @jcalz I voted to close it in favor of the other one. I'm sorry but I posted this question when I thought the solution was to use `Symbol` but I was wrong. Should I just delete it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean something like the following:

```
declare type REACT_APP_ENV_VALUE = "dev" | "production"

type Keys = `urn:${REACT_APP_ENV_VALUE}:claims/user-id`

type ABC = {    
    [key in Keys]: string
}
```

If necessary, you could also add a questionmark, so your keys are optional:

```
type ABC = {    
    [key in Keys]?: string
}
```

Example usage:

```
const x : ABC = {
    "urn:dev:claims/user-id": "123"
}


alert(x['urn:dev:claims/user-id'])
```

This uses [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm just completely unable to access that key afterwards using, for example: `abc[Keys]` to get the value.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by not able to access value. Therefore I've updated my answer so it might be more clear.

Comment: Ok, and how do I refer to 'urn:dev:claims/user-id' dynamically?

Comment: you mean based on your ENV?

Comment: Yes, so for instance: `x[Keys]` except of course the previous refers to a type so does not work.

Comment: Actually this won't work at all because `REACT_APP_ENV_VALUE` is never equal to two literal values as you've suggested in your example unfortunately, it's a purely dynamic and unknown value. So `typeof process.env.REACT_APP_ENV_VALUE` will always be `string`.