# Dynamic String Literal Type from Variable in Typescript

Tags: typescript, string-literals

I'm getting a token with claims from an authentication provider. It's a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
  "email": "user@example.org",
  "urn:dev:claims/user-id": "123"
}
```

I'm trying to create a representative interface or type on my client to access this token keys correctly. The problem is the "dev" part of "urn:dev:claims/user-id" above is dynamic, it comes from environment variable as such:

`const claimKey = urn:${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV}:claims/user-id`

When I try the following:

```
interface MyInterface {
  email: string;
  [claimKey]: string;
}
```

It does not work.

Here's a full reproducible example:

```js
const env = {
  REACT_APP_ENV: "dynamic-value"
}

const token = {
  "email": "user@example.org",
  "urn:dev:claims/user-id": "123"
}

const claimKey = `urn:${env.REACT_APP_ENV}:claims/user-id`

interface MyInterface {
  email: string;
  [claimKey]: string;
}
```

Comment: That `myType` definition isn’t valid TypeScript or JavaScript. Could you edit the code here to be a [mcve]?

Comment: I am missing a question here... ;) ... But I assume that you want to ask how to do this. I can only remark that TypeScript is just a shell over JavaScript that offers some type safety during *compilation* (to JavaScript). So, as far as I know, you cannot use TypeScript type features (like types and interfaces) for any *runtime* behavior. I think you need to provide more context to your question and also include your own attempts so far. That way, it will be easier for others to understand what you are trying to accomplish and to help you in more detail.

Comment: Sorry for that, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJ9ADm), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing and does not have other issues (invalid syntax, etc).  This should include details of any problem: the phrase "it does not work" is generally not sufficient to convey what the issue is; see the "Describe the problem" section of the [mcve] guidelines.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz question updated.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know that it's possible to represent a "unique but unknown `string`" in a way that works with concatenation and doesn't have other side effects.  A workaround like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wj5D7W) might suffice?  If so, I'll write up an answer.  (Please also edit the text of the question so that it's a [mcve] without needing to click a link that brings you outside of Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Typescript is a compiler, it only knows what it can prove about your code from analyzing it, not running it. If the *type* is based on the value of an environmental variable at *runtime*, then Typescript cannot encompass it. You will have to do some runtime assertions or rely on a documented convention. This isn't just a problem with Typescript either: the road to strongly-typed HTTP requests is littered with skulls.

Comment: Thank you @JaredSmith -- but then jcalz's workaround looks like it may resolve the issue to me...

Comment: @Sammy not really type safe though, he mentions it in the playground comment. May or may not really matter to you in this case, but don't expect the compiler to do something it's logically and temporally incapable of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript does not currently have the capacity to do exactly what you're asking for:

- You want the compiler to treat `process.env.REACT_APP_ENV` as some "unknown but unique" `string` literal, much the way that [`unique symbol`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol) works for `symbol`-typed values.  There was an experimental pull request at [microsoft/TypeScript#33038](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33038) which would have allowed things like `unique string`, but it never made it into the language.
- Moreover, you need to be able to *concatenate* that unique string to other string literals and have some sort of unique output; maybe this would also require supporting `unique string` inside "pattern" template literal types as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598), and it isn't obvious that this would work.
- <strike>And even if that were all taken care of, you currently can't use pattern template literal types as object keys; see [microsoft/TypeScript#42192](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42192).  An object type like `` Record<`foo${string}`, number> `` is unfortunately treated very much like `{}`; it will not complain if you assign a type like `{fooOops: "This is not a number"}` to it.</strike> ( Well, at least this part is fixed for TS4.4; pattern template literals can be used in index signatures as per [microsoft/TypeScript#44512](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44512) )

All of that put together means this is just not within the realm of possibility for TypeScript as of TS 4.4.

---

Instead you would need some sort of workaround.  I was toying around with using a [string `enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) to simulate an opaque/nominal subtype of `string` that works with keys, but it doesn't really do anything more useful than the workaround I settled on: a placeholder string literal type like `"###${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV}###"` that we *pretend* is the known actual type of `process.env.REACT_APP_ENV`.  As long as we only refer to the type as `process.env.REACT_APP_ENV` and not as the pretend string literal, everything will work out.  We might even want the pretend value to be something like `"!!!PLACEHOLDER_DO_NOT_USE_THIS!!!"` or whatever you need to convince people not to use the literal type.

It would look like this:

```
declare const process: {
  env: {// the following type is a fiction but is the best I can do 
    REACT_APP_ENV: "###${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV}###"
  }
}
```

And then your `claimKey` would be a [`const`-asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) template string so that the compiler can concatenate it and maintain the string-literal-ness of it:

```
const claimKey = `urn:${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV}:claims/user-id` as const
```

And everything works as desired, mostly:

```
interface MyInterface {
  email: string;
  [claimKey]: string;
}

const myInterface: MyInterface = {
  email: "user@example.org",
  [claimKey]: "123"
}
```

Hooray!  Still, it's just a workaround.  That placeholder value will likely show up as IntelliSense hints, unfortunately:

```
const booIntelliSense: MyInterface = {
  email: "",
  "urn:###${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV}###:claims/user-id": "oops" // <-- hinted by IntelliSense!
}
```

so it's really not perfect.  Oh well.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHcEsBcAsHsCu1QGd4FsCmdIDsBzUAG0gGstRZpoAHVALhAJlkQCMA6AY02A0jcATvHQAzaMAAqAT1pYAysMi1JtRMWLAAzNoAM2gBygAUCFABJAOQZQeeClSIhlBOFDR4oXtlCJaEKygAIZokAAmWAC0WGJiWNzQUWIulABEiHiQAI6IlOzIfnhk9uB4aNBC+ARpZmAm0HKUAFqgALygAEoJ8ELhADwABmLw8AAkAN6oldUAvoMANHaIGOxYQgB8Jrx406AAXgygrR0ToCPwABJYMkdpAKIAGgDCAKoK96AAsvdpoLMAbhMJki3GIwRc3nguxQtBE3CwqEYoAmJlAoCweAAbkcJuY4JQRpp4FBCB4mqBIKgQudBNBINDQAUUFSPLB8oiUBZvMFyuEvGj0V17gBBZ5SAD6IoACtKJfcAHIANTuAGJ1ZM4fAEUjOJisZxOqLxVLZfLlbN1araujZiY7cCdnswcFIBgANI3dqgQbOPAMTXwxGoPXYw3GyUyuWKpWzBgut2oYCIVDrKIRQYhalO6DA-DQdZiYII74yCx4AtCIsl1HorAYV3EI7TKqEIHogDaCY9NwAus2Zm37Y7oXsMGWK4Xi1gjl8J5Xq5RToL6427in1gABLAAD2CGFoxCwnF6NQWgq74Ldnpk-dAaQAjAAmbS1B05pmjcsFzSQBSY1NZ3nKcS2XOsG0gJt7zSc90QyIR-StQNtWDUMDSNMVIzNGNLXVeMrwwJMNyEdNwjSO5RnoP5zH6KIoiofMsHCJkZEsSdf3-XYsAAQmHIA)